# 選択した平仮名を片仮名に変換する方法

Tags: emeditor

選択範囲の平仮名だけを片仮名に変換するにはどうすればよいでしょうか。

できれば「編集」→「高度な操作」のような項目に追加して、ショートカットキーを割り当てることができればありがたいです。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unicode で平仮名からカタカナに変換できる平仮名の文字範囲は U+3041 から U+3096 で、それらに対応するカタカナは、平仮名の文字コードから 0x60 を足した値であることが、Unicode のコード表からわかります。

そこで、EmEditor でファイルを開き、<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> を押して、[置換] ダイアログ ボックスを開きます。そして、

**検索する文字列**: `[\x{3041}-\x{3096}]`
**置換後の文字列**: `\J String.fromCharCode("\0".charCodeAt(0) + 0x60)`

と入力して、[正規表現] を選択して、[すべて置換] ボタンをクリックします。

[image: EmEditor 置換]

以上の操作を 1 回の操作で行いたい場合は、以下のマクロを実行することもできます。

```
document.selection.Replace("[\\x{3041}-\\x{3096}]","\\J String.fromCharCode(\x22\\0\x22.charCodeAt(0) + 0x60)",eeFindReplaceCase | eeReplaceAll | eeFindReplaceRegExp,0);
```

マクロを実行する方法は、以下の通りです。

上記のマクロを、適当なファイル名、例えば `HiraToKata.jsee` という名前で保存します。
EmEditor の [マクロ] メニューの [選択] から、保存したマクロを選択します。
編集したいテキスト ファイルを開き、そのファイルがアクティブ状態で、[マクロ] メニューの [実行] (または <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>) を選択します。すると、マクロが実行されます。

**補足**

置換表現の `\J` に続く表現は、EmEditor 独自の構文で、JavaScript の表現であることを示します。

**参考**

- [正規表現構文](http://www.emeditor.org/ja/howto_search_search_regexp_syntax.html)
- [置換表現構文](http://www.emeditor.org/ja/howto_search_replacement_expression_syntax.html)

Comment: ありがとうございます。上記のマクロを実行すると、対象が文書の全体になってしまいます。選択範囲だけを対象にするにはどうすればよいでしょうか。

Comment: [置換] ダイアログの中の [選択した範囲のみ] をチェックしてください。

Comment: [選択した範囲のみ] のチェックをできればマクロで表現したいのですが、どうすればよいでしょうか。

Comment: `eeFindReplaceSelOnly` フラグを追加してください。次のようになります。 
`document.selection.Replace("[\\x{3041}-\\x{3096}]","\\J String.fromCharCode(\x22\\0\x22.charCodeAt(0) + 0x60)",eeFindReplaceCase | eeReplaceAll | eeFindReplaceRegExp | eeFindReplaceSelOnly,0);`

Comment: たびたびすみません。eeFindReplaceSelOnly フラグを追加したマクロにすると、「エラーを特定できません」というエラーメッセージが表示されます。Version 20.5.4です。

Comment: 変換したい平仮名を含むテキストを選択してから実行していますでしょうか?

Comment: うまくいきました。どうもお騒がせいたしました。