# EmEditor Professionalで選択範囲を「ひらがな→カタカナ変換」「カタカナ→ひらがな変換」ができますでしょうか？

Tags: emeditor

お世話になっております。

事例
「アインシュタイン」→「あいんしゅたいん」です。

これはよく使いそうな機能だと思いますので、マクロとかであるのかも知れませんが、全角、半角変換と同様に選択範囲の変換という一覧に出ておく機能だと思うのですが見当たりませんでした。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0):

ひらがなからカタカナに変換する方法は、[選択した平仮名を片仮名に変換する方法](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/74210/%E9%81%B8%E6%8A%9E%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%E5%B9%B3%E4%BB%AE%E5%90%8D%E3%82%92%E7%89%87%E4%BB%AE%E5%90%8D%E3%81%AB%E5%A4%89%E6%8F%9B%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E6%96%B9%E6%B3%95)を参考にしてください。

逆にカタカナからひらがなに変換するには、次のようにします。

EmEditor でファイルを開き、<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> を押して、[置換] ダイアログ ボックスを開きます。そして、

**検索する文字列**: `[\x{30A1}-\x{30F6}]`
**置換後の文字列**: `\J String.fromCharCode("\0".charCodeAt(0) - 0x60)`

と入力して、[正規表現] を選択して、[すべて置換] ボタンをクリックします。

[image: EmEditor 置換]

以上の操作を 1 回の操作で行いたい場合は、以下のマクロを実行することもできます。

```
document.selection.Replace("[\\x{30A1}-\\x{30F6}]","\\J String.fromCharCode(\x22\\0\x22.charCodeAt(0) - 0x60)",eeFindReplaceCase | eeReplaceAll | eeFindReplaceRegExp | eeFindReplaceSelOnly,0);
```

マクロを実行する方法は、以下の通りです。

上記のマクロを、適当なファイル名、例えば `KataToHira.jsee` という名前で保存します。
EmEditor の [マクロ] メニューの [選択] から、保存したマクロを選択します。
編集したいテキスト ファイルを開き、そのファイルがアクティブ状態で、[マクロ] メニューの [実行] (または <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>) を選択します。すると、マクロが実行されます。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。出来ました。これはよく使うので正規表現ではなく、全角→半角変換のように一覧に出るようにバージョンアップしていただきたい機能です。私は単語登録したので、すぐ出来るようになりましたが、一般は自力で辿り着くのは困難と思います。[ァ-ヴー]→[ぁ-んー]くらいまでしか思いつきませんでした。よろしくお願いいたします。